# can't import basemap library in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

My version of python is 2.7.8 and version of basemap is basemap-1.0.7.win32-py2.7(exe installation). I installed many libraries before and never had any problems.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\examples\simpletest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import pyproj
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mpl_toolkits\basemap\pyproj.py", line 50, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import _proj
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mpl_toolkits\basemap\_proj.py", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name pyproj
```

Comment: Have you tried out http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html

Comment: Have u tried installing pyproj python module

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you install the following, *in this order:*

1. pyproj
2. numpy
3. matplotlib
4. [GEOS](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html)
5. basemap

Comment: Why would the order matter?